# LiteSpeed .htaccess Remove File Extension

Tags: .htaccess, litespeed

I'm usign LiteSpeed 7. I have a .htaccess file for remove file extension but LiteSpeed does not support that.

My .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]  
 </IfModule>
```

My project files required .html and .php files.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

LiteSpeed Web Server is current release 5.2.x and 5.3RC2, seem not 7 yet.

Tried your rule and seems ok. visit www.example.com/phpinfo,  it redirects to www.example.com/phpinfo.php successfully

Maybe you have some other rules after current rule?

Answer (score 0):

I found this Block has to be removed:

```
# Access block for files
# Apache < 2.3
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    <FilesMatch "(?i:^\.|^#.*#|^(?:ChangeLog|ToDo|Readme|License)(?:\.md|\.txt)?|^composer\.(?:json|lock)|^ext_conf_template\.txt|^ext_typoscript_constants\.txt|^ext_typoscript_setup\.txt|flexform[^.]*\.xml|locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)|\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|tsconfig|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql(?:\..*)?|sqlite(?:\..*)?|sw[op]|git.*)|.*(?:~|rc))$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# Apache ≥ 2.3
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#(?i:/\.|/\x23.*\x23|/(?:ChangeLog|ToDo|Readme|License)(?:\.md|\.txt)?|/composer\.(?:json|lock)|/ext_conf_template\.txt|/ext_typoscript_constants\.txt|/ext_typoscript_setup\.txt|flexform[^.]*\.xml|locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)|\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|tsconfig|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql(?:\..*)?|sqlite(?:\..*)?|sw[op]|git.*)|.*(?:~|rc))$#">
        Require all denied
    </If>
</IfModule>
```

But how to replace this?